# Symbolic Group Names (like in Python) in Ruby Regular Expression

Tags: python, ruby, regex

Came across this handy regular expression utility in Python (I am a beginner in Python). e.g. By using the regexp

```
(?P<id>[a-zA-Z_]\w*)
```

I can refer to the matched data as

```
m.group('id')
```

(Full documentation: look for "symbolic group name" [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html))

In Ruby, we can access the matched references using `$1, $2` or using the MatchData object (`m[1], m[2]` etc.). Is there something similar to Python's Symbolic Group Names in Ruby?

Comment: If you're in 1.8 and can't use Onigurama for some reason, an interesting alternative might be Jim Weirich's [re](http://github.com/jimweirich/re) library

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Older Ruby releases didn't have named groups (tx Alan for pointing this out in a comment!), but, if you're using Ruby 1.9...:

`(?<name>subexp)` expresses a named group in Ruby expressions too; `\k<name>` is the way you back-reference a named group in substitution, if that's what you're looking for!

Comment: Be aware that named groups are a feature of the new Oniguruma regex engine.  It replaced Ruby's old, underpowered regex engine quite recently, in Ruby 1.9, so there's a lot of reference material out there that hasn't caught up with the change.

Comment: There's an Oniguruma gem for 1.8, though you'll need to install Oniguruma first to be able to use it - http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/index.xhtml

Comment: Thanks - I searched a but more. Ruby 1.8 can be compiled with the Oniguruma library (and Ruby 1.9 can optionally be compiled with the older Ruby 1.8 regex implementation).

http://angryruby.blogspot.com/2007/05/oniguruma-and-named-regexes-in-ruby-18.html

And Regular Expressions Cookbook (http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520694) talks about this.

Answer (score 10):

Ruby 1.9 introduced named captures:

```
m = /(?<prefix>[A-Z]+)(?<hyphen>-?)(?<digits>\d+)/.match("THX1138.")
m.names # => ["prefix", "hyphen", "digits"]
m.captures # => ["THX", "", "1138"]
m[:prefix] # => "THX"
```

You can use `\k<prefix>`, etc, for back-references.

Comment: Yes - with the Oniguruma engine.